# CheckBox to Highlight Range Google Sheets Formula/ Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

[image]

I am trying to get the result in the image attached. If I check a checkBox in Column A, I want it to also to highlight the same SKU & Location Column H,I(in Bright Green). Conditional formatting or if script could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH($H2&$I2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER($B$2:$B&$C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=TRUE)))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=REGEXMATCH($H2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Hi Player0 - I have copied the formula. it is only returning the same row that has been checked in Column A. I would like it to return ALL Sku`s from H:I From whats been ckecked in Column A. In the above example I selected A20823 & there were 9 results in H:I so those 9 get highlighted. Thank you

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet? try updated answer

Comment: Player0 - your update answer solved the problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve this using [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). These are the steps to follow:

1. Select the cell that you want to highlight with the checkbox, right click on it.
2. Go to conditional formation
3. Under Conditional format rules -> Format rules select custom formula is under (format cells if) and below it =A2 *(or the checkbox cell basically)*
4. Choose the color and press done and you will be ready!

[image]

Hope this has helped you, let me know if you need anything else (like an Apps Script implementation of this) or if you did not understand anything.